# Is there a way to 'reset' a jQuery function each time it is triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an eCommerce website product page for a product with color options.

I'm trying to copy the selected color attribute value and append it to the product title, and I'm using any change to the value of #pa_finish as a trigger, to ensure the title is updated with the current selection.

Here is the code I'm presently using:

```
        $( '#pa_finish' ).change(function(){         
                
           var var_name = $('#pa_finish :selected').text();
           var original = $('h1.product_title.entry-title').text();
            
           $('h1.product_title.entry-title').html(original + ' ' + var_name);

        });
```

The issue I'm having is that, instead of the title refreshing with each trigger, the var_name variable is being iterated alongside the previous value, so the product title ends up simply increasing in length!

Ideally, the pre-existing text value from var_name is cleared, and replaced with the new selection each time a change is made.

Is there a means by which I can 'reset' the function each time it is triggered? Thank you in advance for any help or insight anyone might be able to provide.

Comment: `var_name` does not retain its value between executions of this function.  It is initialized to the value in `$('#pa_finish :selected').text()` every time.  It sounds like you're making a false assumption in your debugging.  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: You can store a base name as a jQuery `.data()` property on one of the elements involved.

Comment: Store the original value only once outside the function, so it does not get reread every time the function gets called.

Comment: The issue isn't resetting "the function", it's resetting the .entry-title that is affected by the function.  Store the initial value in a `.data()` property and restore it at the start of the function.  eg `var title = $('h1.product_title.entry-title');  if (title.data("original") == "") title.data("original", title.text()); var original = title.data("original");`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your input - I've realised that, as pointed out in the comments, I hadn't established a baseline value for my title.

I have a working example now:

```
var title = $('h1.product_title.entry-title').text();
  
$( '#pa_finish' ).change(function() {
    var var_name = $('#pa_finish :selected').text();
            
    $('h1.product_title.entry-title').html(title + ' ' + var_name);
});
```

I've established a value for the original title in a 'title' variable (outside of the function), so that when the function executes it replaces the HTML of:

```
$('h1.product_title.entry-title')
```

...with a combination of the original title and the var_name variable, on each change.

Before, it was simply loading the selector again and again, and tagging on the result of var_name, which is why I saw the repitition.

I hope this can help someone in the future.